# Android Gradle build release EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In my project I decide to include [Appsee](https://www.appsee.com/) Library, but as soon as I did it I start receiving `Exception From Simulation` error when trying to run `gradle assembleRelease` and build release version of my app. Here is the error log:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':startActivity:dexRelease'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/hardartcore/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx -JXmx4g --dex --output /Users/hardartcore/Desktop/sworkspace/Work/startActivity/build/intermediates/dex/release --input-list=/Users/hardartcore/Desktop/sworkspace/Work/startActivity/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/release/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION:
    expected type int but found cfz
    ...at bytecode offset 0000000d
    ...while working on block 000d
    ...while working on method <clinit>:()V
    ...while processing <clinit> ()V
    ...while processing cfz.class
    1 error; aborting
```

I did some research in google, but didn't see any explanation about this kind of error and why this is happening. If I remove `AppSee` jar library everything works fine and I can build my app.

And my **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.14.7'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven'
    }
}

android {

    signingConfigs {
        release_config {
            storeFile file('****')
            keyAlias '*****'
            keyPassword '*****'
            storePassword '*****'
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.startactivity"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        renderscriptTargetApi 20
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release_config
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "true"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "false"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':nineOldAndroids')
    compile project(':robotoTextView')
    compile project(':roundedImageView')
    compile project(':securePreferences')
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':styledDialogs')
    compile project(':swipeListView')
    compile project(':memorizingActivity')
    compile project(':photoView')
    compile project(':apptentiveandroidsdk')
    compile project(':floatingActionButton')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile files('libs/asmack-android-8-4.0.4-SNAPSHOT-2014-08-20.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v4_5_1_sdkonly.jar')
    compile files('libs/logentries-android-2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-2.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-urlconnection-2.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.xbill.dns_2.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.1.13'
    compile files('libs/appsee.jar') // THIS CAUSE THE ERROR
    // Google Play Services separated APIs
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

P.S. This happens only when I am building release version, in debug mode it's not happening.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can only make it work using proguard-android.txt (basically turn off all optimization by ProGuard). Still back and forth with AppSee support for alternative solutions...

Comment: I've already talk with them with this issue and they didn't find any solution yet, neither do I for now, but I can't turn off all optimization from ProGuard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after a few researches and contacting to `Appsee` support, I found out the solution to my own question. Yes, it was a problem because of appsee jar, but the main reason was `org.jcodec` package which were used by this jar. So including these settings in your proguard file should fix this issue:

```
# AppSee integration
-optimizations !code/*,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!method/*
-keep class com.appsee.** { *; }
-keep class org.jcodec.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.appsee.**
```

Hope this helps somebody else!

Comment: I had the same problem, and I fixed it with you answer and also manually upgrading my proguard version to 5.2.1

Comment: You can actually just do the keep class part without turning off optimization.  The only down side is it just takes AGES to run proguard!